# get all content of div including content of iframes using javascripts not jquery

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I Have a div something like this

```
<div id="tid">
   <iframe>
       <html>
           <body>
           <scripts></scripts>
           <iframe>...
              //more content
           <ifram>
           </body>
       </html>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

I want to get below using javascript.

```
<iframe>
    <html>
        <body>
           <scripts></scripts>
               <iframe>...
                  //more content and cannot guess how many iframes are there.
              <ifram>
         </body>
     </html>
</iframe>
```

InnerHtml only return first iframe only. I tried with .contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML. but this only return first iframe. I want get all the content into string variable without using jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can not do this because of same origin policy

Answer (score 6):

**YOU NEED TO REPLACE `<` WITH `&lt;` AND `>` WITH `&gt;` TO PRINT `HTML` TAGS AS A PLAIN TEXT.**

**try this code,**

```
 var content = document.getElementById('tid').innerHTML;
 content = content.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;"); 
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = content;
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yalaqeta/1/)**

if you want to reuse that `div` `html`, simply add that `content` to any other `html` element like below,

```
 var content = document.getElementById('tid').innerHTML;
  //the variable content contains the html inside "tid" div.
  var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'newDiv';
iDiv.innerHTML = content;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wuzijalo/1/)**

Comment: thanks,,this is working with my example, but not working with actual scenario. actual is like ad sense html. i want to get that whole html in div.

Comment: what do mean by whole html div? you don't want to print the html as plain text? did you want to use div html contents in another place?

Comment: i dont want print,,i want to take scripts and all content into a variable. in actula case iframe content can get only one level. but i don't know how many iframes are there :(

Comment: document.getElementById('tid').innerHTML,,,this will not give all child element contents. that is where I stuck. I appreciate if you can try with adsense code. thank you very much

Comment: did you mean iframe inside iframe scenario?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49551/discussion-between-syard-gate-and-cj-ramki)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the body tags this should work.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var allContent = "";

for (var i=0; i < els.length; i++) {
     allContent += els[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeID');
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

now you can use iframeDocument to access content of iframe, jquery does the same

**UPDATE**

You can do something like this ..

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("tid");
var iframes = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

// now loop over the iframes 

for(iframe in iframes){
  var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
  var internalIframes = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
  if(internalIframes.length > 1){
     // start the for in loop again
  }

}
```

Comment: these iframes do not have id's and can not determine by class (dynamically generates). And have no idea how many nested iframes in here.